# How to find all solutions of a partially filled Sudoku board

Tags: algorithm, sudoku, backtracking

I know how to get ONE solution for a partially filled Sudoku board by using backtracking algorithm, but I am not sure how to get all solutions if the board has more than one solutions. Is there an algorithm for this?

Here is the code sample that I tried to generate all solutions, but it repeatedly generates the same solution and I am not sure what the problem is.

```
boolean solve(Stack<Integer> emptyLocationList) { 
    if(emptyLocationList.size()==0) return false;
    int emptyId = emptyLocationList.peek();
    int row = emptyId/9, col = emptyId%9;

    for(int val=1; val<=9; val++) {
        if(isSafe(board, row, col, val)) {
            // set value
            board[row][col] = val;
            emptyLocationList.pop();

            // move forward
            if(solve(emptyLocationList)) return true;

            // backtrack
            board[row][col] = 0; 
            emptyLocationList.push(emptyId);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Explanation:

- emptyLocationList: stack of empty spots of the original partially filled board
- isSafe(board, row, col, val): whether it is safe to put `val` at `(row, col)` in `board`

When I change `if(emptyLocationList.size()==0) return false;` into `if(emptyLocationList.size()==0) return true;`, it will successfully generate one solution.

Comment: The same algorithm, just do not stop it after the 1st success.

Comment: @PM77-1 I added the major part of the code I wrote which didn't work as expected. Could you take a look at the edited problem and let me know where the problem is? Thanks a lot.